# Definite integration of a matrix

Tags: integration, matrices, definite-integrals, matrix-calculus

$$f(x) =\begin{vmatrix}
            x^3 &  \cos^2x & 2x^4 \\
            \tan^3x & 1 & \sec2x \\
            \sin^3x & x^4 & 5 \\
            \end{vmatrix}
$$

Then $\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \det(f(x))\,dx$ is equal to ?

The way I thought of solving it was by making use of the fact some of these are odd functions and Hence their integration along the given intervals would give a result of zero , but since some of them are even functions i cant directly remove them . I thought of opening up the determinant of the 3x3 matrix ,but this would result in even more complicated functions .

This question was in a competitive exam where on average 3 mins can be given to per question ,so is there an approach do solve it In a more decent way ?

**The answer given is $0$.**

Comment: What about the discriminant?

Comment: This is the discriminant, as in this matrix we need to find the value of the discriminant in the given limits

Comment: I’m sorry if the question is a bit unclear .

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(x)=-f(-x)$ by linearity of the determinant. So $f$ is an odd function being integrated on a symmetric interval around 0...

Comment: you probably mean multi-linearity of the determinant, not linearity.